# How to use putextra () in Kotin

Tags: kotlin, android-intent

I want to send data (number) from "edit text section" of Sub-Activity1 (users input a simple number)and receive in another Sub-activity2, and depending on the number I want to show different sets of text. I am a beginner and I am stuck where in Sub-Activity 2 as it returns error for `val str` where I want to receive and manipulate the number received from Sub-Activity 1 `editText`.

Sub-Activity 1 :
<Send & Open Sub-Activity2>

```
getResult.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, subactivity::class.java)
            val name:  String = editTextID.getText().toString()
            intent.putExtra(name:"editTextID",value:"7.0")
            startActivity(intent)
```

This returns no error.

Sub-Activity 2: <Receive & Manipulate the text>

```
class subactivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subactivity2)
        val str =intent.getStringExtra("editTextID")
        when str == 7.0 {
            infoTextView.textview.text= "textIwannaShow"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Franz might be right about you wanting to pass a `Double`, but since you're passing it as a `String` and also naming your val `str`, I'll assume you do want to pass a string (that just happens to represent a number). In which case you need to compare to a string

```
if (str == "7.0") {
    infoTextView.textview.text = "textIwannaShow"
}
```

or if you do want a `when` block

```
when(str) {
    "7.0" -> infoTextView.textview.text = "textIwannaShow"
}
```

If you actually want to work with numbers you'll have to call `toDouble()` on your string at some point to convert it to one. `toDoubleOrNull` would be better if you're taking that number from a text input (in case the user doesn't enter a valid number), but you're not actually using the value taken from the `EditText`

Comment: Actually you are right that users might input string and your lines of code solved the error, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your Sub-Activity 2, you are receiving a `String` not an `Integer`.

So, you should change your code from this

```
val str =intent.getStringExtra("editTextID")
```

To this

```
val str =intent.getIntExtra("editTextID", 0)
```

Anyway, in the example you are passing `7.0` which is `Double`, so you probably need this instead of above code

```
val str =intent.getDoubleExtra("editTextID", 0.0)
```

Comment: It was useful to know different patterns to handle double / integer, so, thank you Franz!

Comment: sure, no problem :)